# How do I build and install P4Python for Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, perforce, p4python

I've been unable to build [P4Python](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/loadsupp.html#api) for an Intel Mac OS X 10.5.5.

These are my steps:

1. I downloaded p4python.tgz (from
   http://filehost.perforce.com/perforce/r07.3/tools/) and expanded
   it into "P4Python-2007.3".
2. I downloaded p4api.tar (from
   http://filehost.perforce.com/perforce/r07.3/bin.macosx104x86/)
   and expanded it into "p4api-2007.3.143793".
3. I placed "p4api-2007.3.143793" into "P4Python-2007.3" and edited
   setup.cfg to set "p4_api=./p4api-2007.3.143793".
4. I added the line 'extra_link_args = ["-framework", "Carbon"]' to
   setup.py after:

   ```
   elif unameOut[0] == "Darwin":
       unix = "MACOSX"
       release = "104"
       platform = self.architecture(unameOut[4])
   ```
5. I ran `python setup.py build` and got:

$ python setup.py build

```
API Release 2007.3
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'P4API' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-double -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DID_OS="MACOSX104X86" -DID_REL="2007.3" -DID_PATCH="151416" -DID_API="2007.3" -DID_Y="2008" -DID_M="04" -DID_D="09" -I./p4api-2007.3.143793 -I./p4api-2007.3.143793/include/p4 -I/build/toolchain/mac32/python-2.4.3/include/python2.4 -c P4API.cpp -o build/temp.darwin-9.5.0-i386-2.4/P4API.o -DOS_MACOSX -DOS_MACOSX104 -DOS_MACOSXX86 -DOS_MACOSX104X86
cc1plus: warning: command line option "-Wstrict-prototypes" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
P4API.cpp: In function âint P4Adapter_init(P4Adapter*, PyObject*, PyObject*)â:
P4API.cpp:105: error: âPy_ssize_tâ was not declared in this scope
P4API.cpp:105: error: expected `;' before âposâ
P4API.cpp:107: error: âposâ was not declared in this scope
P4API.cpp: In function âPyObject* P4Adapter_run(P4Adapter*, PyObject*)â:
P4API.cpp:177: error: âPy_ssize_tâ was not declared in this scope
P4API.cpp:177: error: expected `;' before âiâ
P4API.cpp:177: error: âiâ was not declared in this scope
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

`which gcc` returns /usr/bin/gcc and `gcc -v` returns:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin9
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5465~16/src/configure
--disable-checking -enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man
--enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++
--program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.0/
--with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.0.0 --with-slibdir=/usr/lib
--build=i686-apple-darwin9 --with-arch=apple --with-tune=generic
--host=i686-apple-darwin9 --target=i686-apple-darwin9
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)
```

`python -V` returns Python 2.4.3.

Comment: It would probably be useful to do the compile with LC_ALL=C so that gcc outputs ordinary quotes, rather than extended characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newer version 2008.1 will build with Python 2.4.

I had posted the minor changes required to do that on my P4Python page, but they were rolled in to the official version.

Robert

Answer (score 1):

From http://bugs.mymediasystem.org/?do=details&task_id=676 suggests that Py_ssize_t was added in python 2.5, so it won't work (without some modifications) with python 2.4.

Either install/compile your own copy of python 2.5/2.6, or work out how to change P4Python, or look for an alternative python-perforce library.

Answer (score 0):

Very outdated, but maybe you can use http://public.perforce.com:8080/@md=d&cd=//guest/miki_tebeka/p4py/&c=5Fm@//guest/miki_tebeka/p4py/main/?ac=83 for now