# Installing P4Python on Mac OS 10.6.7

Tags: python, perforce

[I've found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168273/how-do-i-build-and-install-p4python-for-mac-os-x) and it seems a bit out of date. So I'm hoping someone else has had this same problem.
I'm trying to install P4Python using [these instructions](ftp://ftp.perforce.com/pub/perforce/r10.2/doc/user/p4pythonnotes.txt). 
After running the setup.py script, when I try to run p4test.py as the instructions request, I fail all but 4 tests. 
I've downloaded the 10.2/bin.macosx105u p4api, I have gcc 4.2.1, and Python 2.6.1

I'm sure I've left out an important piece of information, so please just let me know what else is needed and I'll edit this post.

**Edit:** A note for any one else looking at this, I wasn't able to get the [bin.macosx105u](ftp://ftp.perforce.com/pub/perforce/r10.2/bin.macosx105u/) version of P4Api to compile correctly. Everything did work however when I used the [bin.darwin90u](ftp://ftp.perforce.com/pub/perforce/r10.2/bin.darwin90u/) version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the `p4d` executable on your machine? See the Note in step 4 of the installation instructions. If `p4d` isn't there, it's quite possible that a lot of tests fail.

If you indeed don't have it (and don't want to or can't install it), then go ahead and continue with the installation and see if the P4API works.

Comment: I absolutely missed that part. Thank you.